# Unwanted animation on page load with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, css-animations

I have a page with an element that has an animation on hide/show. The page loads when the element is not shown but still, when the page loads it shows the hide animation.
I've even tried to change the condition to `ng-show="false"` and still I see the hide animation when page loads.
I've understood that there was an old problem with angularjs about this but I'm using 1.2.2.

HTML:

```
<div class="c_redDiv" ng-show="state == true">
            <div ...>
                <button ...>
                    <div ... />
                </button>
                <button ...>
                    <div ... />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.c_redDiv.ng-hide-add, .c_redDiv.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
    display: block !important;
}

.c_redDiv.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.c_redDiv.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 1;
    top: -50px;
}

.c_redDiv.ng-hide-add,
.c_redDiv.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0px
}
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem with 1.2.23

Comment: No and I'm sorry but I'm not handling with it currently.

Answer (score 0):

you should add to your css:

```
.c_redDiv{
    display:none;
}


.c_redDiv.ng-show{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way to avoid the initial animation triggering when `ng-hide` or `ng-show` is used, but was able to get it working with `ng-if`.

HTML:

```
<div class="c_redDiv" ng-if="state == true">
 ...
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.c_redDiv {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.35s ease;

  &.ng-leave, &.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  &.ng-leave.ng-leave-active, &.ng-enter {
    max-height: 0;
  }
}
```